# The form does not open in center of the parent by using a Thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a main window form (not MDI form) and when i do some process, until this process finishes, i want to show another form (a waiting form)

If i do that regular way like that

```
   ProgressForm = new FrmProgress();                                                             
   ProgressForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
   ProgressForm.ShowDialog();
```

it works but it stucks in ShowDialog function until I close the form. I know the logic here.

Thats why I called this code with a thread like

```
Thread splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
                        delegate
                        {
                            ProgressForm = new FrmProgress();
                            ProgressForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

                            ProgressForm.ShowDialog();
                            //Application.Run(ProgressForm);
                        }
                    ));

            splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            splashThread.Start();
    //this part is my job

            PackageExtracter packageExtracter = new PackageExtracter();
            packageExtracter.InstallPackage(openDlg.FileName);

            ProgressForm.Invoke(new Action(ProgressForm.Close));
            MessageboxHelper.ShowInfoMessage(Messages.MsgPackageInstalledSuccessfully, Messages.MsgInstallPackageTitle);
            ProgressForm.Dispose();
            ProgressForm = null;
```

but this time it opens top-left corner in the first monitor (evne my main application is on the second monitor)

I want to show the "waiting form" as modal and when my job finished, then hide the form.

IS there any idea?

Comment: Well, I don't think that `ProgressForm` can know who its parent is if you open it from a different thread. If memory serves me right, `ShowDialog` has an overload that accepts the owner window. Did you try passing an instance of your main form to that overload when you open the form? It's just an idea, I never needed to do this. Also, evaluate the option of doing work in the background if it's not something that must absolutely finish before the user can carry on using your app. `async/await` would help here.

Comment: s,m, is right, the ProgressForm doesn't know the mainform, cause it is in another thread. Your best bet would be to start your work in a BackgroundWorker or another method to run it in background. After you started the worker thread you would hook the ProgressForm up to some event, reporting the progress and then show it with ShowDialog.

Comment: @s.m. thank you for your reply. I could do with a longer way but i do not want it. async seems good. I will try that.

Comment: Do you want the form as Model (Always on top) as defined in your question, or in the center (as defined in your title)? Or do you want to fix the fact that your splashscreen does not return from `ShowDialog`?

Comment: @BoeseB, thank you for your answer. I thought so.. But firstly If i can solve it with a simply thread it could be better. Otherwise I will do what you say

Comment: @MartinMulder, It will be like a splash screen that shows user "you have to wait, the process takes time" its kind of a warning box

Comment: @ertan2002 instead of using another windows you could also use an overlay in the main window to show your message and toggle the visibility for when the user has to wait

Comment: You could do it the dirty way and handle `ProgressForm.Shown` and start your work from there, thereby avoiding fumbling with multiple UI threads, which is always tricky business. Or you could pass in a callback to `ProgressForm` and have it call the delegate to start your work and exit when it's done. Or you could call `Show` instead of `ShowDialog` and then disable the owner form. Not sure about this, but it could work.

Comment: @BoeseB, yes but I have been designing a management console app. I do not want to make it dirty like that. Because I have several that kind of situation :)

Comment: @s.m. yes exactly kind of event/delegate will do this job. I was only looking for a solution with my code but it seems it will not work like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like that

```
            Thread splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
                delegate
                {
                    ProgressForm = new FrmProgress();
                    Application.Run(ProgressForm);
                }
            ));

            splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            splashThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title mentions you want it to show in the center of another form.  It looks like you haven't set the parent form for the ProgressForm.  You can set this by passing the parent form into the ShowDialog method.

```
ProgressForm.ShowDialog(someParentForm);
```

However, i'm not confident that this will work if a different UI thread owns the someParentForm object.

--

If you only want the progress to be in the center of the screen then you can use CenterScreen instead of CenterParent:

```
   ProgressForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
   ProgressForm.ShowDialog();
```